# .htaccess, делает не нужный редирект с поддомена

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Есть два сайта http://www.poll-decor.ru/ и http://knauf.poll-decor.ru/ недавно я переделал первый сайт и настроил редиректы со старых страниц, но получилась неприятная вещь. Некоторые редиректы коснулись и второго сайта и делают редирект на основной сайт.
Пример общего редиректа:

```
Redirect 301 /o-kompanii.html http://www.poll-decor.ru/pages/o-nas.html
```

Как сделать редирект независимым для поддомена?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно переписать сам редирект, указав нужный домен в условиях редиректа:

```
# Проверка домена. Редирект будет действителен только для www.poll-decor.ru
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.poll\-decor\.ru$
# Полный адрес указывать необязательно
RewriteRule ^o\-kompanii\.html$ /pages/o-nas.html [R=301,L]
```

Проверить можно тут: **[htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)**

**Update:**

Если нужно исключить только поддомен knauf:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^knauf
RewriteRule o-kompanii.html /pages/o-nas.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: я так понимаю работает только для полного домена с www я без него как? Прошу ответить в качестве бонуса

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Если я вас неправильно понял, укажите примеры

Comment: к примеру будет третий сайт на данный момент не известный, например super.poll-decor.ru при двух условиях выше на этом домене тоже будет подхватываться редирект, а это не нужно. Применить условие и для нового поддомена теперь будет не трудно, но красивее было бы без лишних тело движений.

Comment: @shaman888 вы заблуждаетесь. super.poll-decor.ru не то же самое, что и www.poll-decor.ru. Первый вариант вам подходит. Редирект не будет срабатывать нигде, кроме как на www.poll-decor.ru

Comment: верно, я поспешил. как я понимаю и на poll-decor.ru без www тоже работать не будет

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли.

Comment: Первый вариант как оказалось не всегда работает мне предложили следующий рабочий вариант: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.poll\-decor\.ru$
#RewriteRule /o-kompanii.html /pages/o-nas.html [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /o-kompanii.html http://www.poll-decor.ru/pages/o-nas.html

Comment: @shaman888 , если уж экранировать специальные знаки, то экранировать везде. В том числе и в RewriteRule. Плюс для железобетонного варианта нужно указать начало и конец строки в правиле.

Answer (score 0):

То, что ты пишешь в корне основного домена, будет распространятся и на поддомены потому что, корневой htaccess имеет более высокий приоритет.

Вариант решения - вынести поддомен выше корня, если функции панели это позволяют.